# Method does not work within the object in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I created a simple object that has a method to return some calculation but it doesn't work.

I declared the object with its properties and method as in the attached code.

```
<p id="demo"></p>
<script>
    var person = new Object();
    person.firstName= "John";
    person.lastName= "Doe";
    person.age=40;
    person.retireAtAge= function (){ return (this.age+25);};
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=person.firstName + " Retires at " + person.retireAtAge;
 </script>
```

The expected output is:
`John Retires at 65`

but I get now is:
`John Retires at function (){ return (this.age+25);}`

Answer (score 3):

You need to call the method by putting `()` at the end of function variable.

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=person.firstName + " Retires at " + person.retireAtAge();
```